# Creating a function with an argument passed to dplyr::filter what is the best way to work around nse?

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

Non standard evaluation is really handy when 
using dplyr's verbs. But it can be problematic when using those
verbs with function arguments. 
For example let us say that I want to create a function that 
gives me the number of rows for a given species.

```
# Load packages and prepare data
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)
# I prefer lowercase column names
names(iris) <- tolower(names(iris))
# Number of rows for all species
nrow(iris)
# [1] 150
```

## Example not working

This function doesn't work as expected because `species`
is interpreted in the context of the iris data frame
instead of being interpreted in the context of the
function argument:

```
nrowspecies0 <- function(dtf, species){
    dtf %>%
        filter(species == species) %>%
        nrow()
}
nrowspecies0(iris, species = "versicolor")
# [1] 150
```

## 3 examples of implementation

To work around non standard evaluation, 
I usually append the argument with an underscore :

```
nrowspecies1 <- function(dtf, species_){
    dtf %>%
        filter(species == species_) %>%
        nrow()
}

nrowspecies1(iris, species_ = "versicolor")
# [1] 50
# Because of function name completion the argument
# species works too
nrowspecies1(iris, species = "versicolor")
# [1] 50
```

It is not completely satisfactory
since it changes the name of the function argument to 
something less user friendly. Or it relies on autocompletion
which I'm  afraid is not a good practice for programming.
To keep a nice argument name,
I could do :

```
nrowspecies2 <- function(dtf, species){
    species_ <- species
    dtf %>%
        filter(species == species_) %>%
        nrow()
}
nrowspecies2(iris, species = "versicolor")
# [1] 50
```

Another way to work around non standard evaluation 
based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26509961/2641825).
`interp()` interprets `species` in the context of the 
function environment:

```
nrowspecies3 <- function(dtf, species){
    dtf %>%
        filter_(interp(~species == with_species, 
                       with_species = species)) %>%
        nrow()
}
nrowspecies3(iris, species = "versicolor")
# [1] 50
```

Considering the 3 function above,
what is the preferred - most robust - way to implement this filter function?
Are there any other ways?

Comment: Data frame column names quotation is one of the reasons I start to prefer python. See [Tidyverse style pandas](https://stmorse.github.io/journal/tidyverse-style-pandas.html#parting-thoughts): ""“_Tidyverse allows a mix of quoted and unquoted references to variable names. In my (in)experience, the convenience this brings is accompanied by equal consternation. It seems to me a lot of the problems solved by tidyeval would not exist if all variables were quoted all the time, as in pandas, but there are likely deeper truths I’m missing here…_”""

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer from **@eddi** is correct about what's going on here.
I'm writing another answer that addresses the larger request of how to write functions using `dplyr` verbs. You'll note that, ultimately, it uses something like `nrowspecies2` to avoid the `species == species` tautology.

To *write a function wrapping dplyr verb(s) that will work with NSE*, write two functions:

**First** write a version that requires quoted inputs, using `lazyeval` and 
an SE version of the `dplyr` verb. So in this case, `filter_`.

```
nrowspecies_robust_ <- function(data, species){ 
  species_ <- lazyeval::as.lazy(species) 
  condition <- ~ species == species_ # *
  tmp <- dplyr::filter_(data, condition) # **
  nrow(tmp)
} 
nrowspecies_robust_(iris, ~versicolor)
```

**Second** make a version that uses NSE:

```
nrowspecies_robust <- function(data, species) { 
  species <- lazyeval::lazy(species) 
  nrowspecies_robust_(data, species) 
} 
nrowspecies_robust(iris, versicolor)
```

***** = if you want to do something more complex, you may need to use `lazyeval::interp` here as in the tips linked below

****** =  also, if you need to change output names, see the `.dots` argument

- For the above, I followed [some tips from Hadley](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/manipulatr/_C3x4kvXo-A/4Nst_7h-FAAJ)
- Another good resource is [the dplyr vignette on NSE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html), which illustrates `.dots`, `interp`, and other functions from the `lazyeval` package
- For even more details on lazyeval [see it's vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html)
- For a thorough discussion of the base R tools for working with NSE (many of which `lazyeval` helps you avoid), see [the chapter on NSE](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) in Advanced R

Comment: Thanks, the email from Hadley you mentioned made me look at  `vignette("lazyeval")` which explains that "Every function that uses NSE should have a standard evaluation (SE) escape hatch that does the actual computation. The SE-function name should end with _." I would  like an explanation of what Hadley means by "suitable for programming with" at the end of the `lazyeval` vignette. Does that imply that I should not use nse inside functions?

Comment: Yes, or at least you should avoid it when possible. Also check out section "Downsides of non-standard evaluation" here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html The basic issue, as Hadley explains in that chapter, is NSE is very hard to reason about within a program because functions may _act differently in different contexts_. That is, when used interactively, an NSE function may act differently than when used in a function.

Comment: Hadley explains the concept of "referential transparency" in [his keynote at the 2016 UseR conference](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Towards-a-grammar-of-interactive-graphics) (at 38min30s). "formula keep both the code and the environment in which this code should be evaluated, without actually doing the evaluation." I created an example using a formula and pasted it in a new answer.

Answer (score 5):

This question has absolutely nothing to do with non standard evaluation. Let me rewrite your initial function to make that clear:

```
nrowspecies4 <- function(dtf, boo){
    dtf %>%
        filter(boo == boo) %>%
        nrow()
}
nrowspecies4(iris, boo = "versicolor")
#150
```

The expression inside your `filter` always evaluates to `TRUE` (almost always - see example below), that's why it doesn't work, not because of some NSE magic.

Your `nrowspecies2` is the way to go.

Fwiw, `species` in your `nrowspecies0` is indeed evaluated as a column, not as the input variable `species`, and you can check that by comparing `nrowspecies0(iris, NA)` to `nrowspecies4(iris, NA)`.

Comment: Not sure why, but this didn't work for me. I ended up using `filter_` as suggested in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38898434/4190925) below. (E: my function used also `group_by` and passed the result further so maybe this was the reason)

Answer (score 1):

[in his 2016 UseR talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Towards-a-grammar-of-interactive-graphics) (@38min30s), Hadley Wickham explains the concept of [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) . Using a formula, the filter function can be reformulated as:

```
nrowspecies5 <- function(dtf, formula){
    dtf %>%
        filter_(formula) %>%
        nrow()
}
```

This has the added benefit of beeing more generic

```
# Make column names lower case
names(iris) = tolower(names(iris)) 
nrowspecies5(iris, ~ species == "versicolor")
# 50
nrowspecies5(iris, ~ sepal.length > 6 & species == "virginica")
# 41
nrowspecies5(iris, ~ sepal.length > 6 & species == "setosa")
# 0
```

Comment: This throws the error `Error: object 'species' not found`

Comment: That's because I like to have al my column names as lower case, I updated the answer with `names(iris) = tolower(names(iris))` anyway, `filter_()` is deprecated so I should probably modify the answer more extensively.