# Unable to scope variables into R functions for `standardize::standardize`

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, scoping, standardized

I am trying to create a custom function that allows me to apply mixed effects standardization to a large dplyr data frame using the `standardize` package.

I have been unsuccessful is parsing function arguments into the standardize function despite having tried various forms of quosure, using `!!`, lazy evaluation and using `do.call`.

I have reviewed the information in these threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647468/creating-a-function-with-an-argument-passed-to-dplyrfilter-what-is-the-best-wa), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558523/showing-string-in-formula-and-not-as-variable-in-lm-fit)) and tried to implement them.

```
# example_df

df <- data.frame(
subject = rep( c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05"), 1, each = 5),
time = rep(1:5, 5),
x = rnorm(25, 0, 1) )
library(dplyr)
df <- tbl_df(df) %>% mutate(subject = factor(subject))

library(standardize)

quick_mixed_efx <- function(df, col){
st_x <- standardize(!!col ~ time + 1| subject, data = df)}

quick_mixed_efx(df, x)
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x' not found

Another (failed) attempt:

```
q_m_efx_2 <- function(df, col){
s_form <- !! col ~ time + 1 | subject
st_x <- do.call("standardize", list(formula = s_form, data = df))
return(st_x) }
```

`q_m_efx2(df, x)` gives the same error.

Ideally, I would like to be able to extract, directly, the standardized data from the function as per:

```
st_x <- standardize(x ~ time + 1|subject, data = df)

st_x$data$x
```

Which works fine outside of a function

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!!` syntax is implemented by the `rlang` package and is only available for use in functions that are expecting such a value (such as the functions in "tidyverse" pacakages). It is not a general purpose way to deal with non-standard evaluation. In particular, the current version of the `standardize` does not support this syntax for variable expansion. Therefore you must use the more traditional methods.

Here's how you can re-write your function using the `substitute()` function

```
quick_mixed_efx <- function(df, col) {
  form <- substitute(col ~ time + 1| subject)
  standardize(form, data = df)}

quick_mixed_efx(df, x)
```

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick that works, however I cannot build in `substitute()` to extract the data from the function. e.g. <br/>
   `quick_mixed_efx <- function(df, col) {
     form <- substitute(col ~ time + 1| subject)
     res <- standardize(form, data =df)
     output <- substitute(res$data$col)
     return(output) }`
<br/>
`a1 <-  quick_mixed_efx(df,x)
str(a1)`  
<br/>
>  language structure(list(call = standardize(formula = form, data = df),      scale = 1, formula = x ~ time + 1 | subject, family = structure(list(

Comment: to extract the elements from the standardized object from within the function this worked:
`quick_mixed_efx <- function(df, col) {  form <- substitute(col ~ time + 1| subject); st_x <- standardize(form, data = df); output <= st_x$data[, as.character (substitute(col) ) ) [,1] ; return (output)}`