# Shiny App - dplyr

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I have a data frame (df) with has four columns (alpha, beta, gamma and delta). Data in each of the columns is an integer. I’m writing a shiny app in which when the user chooses one of the options (options 1 -4) it matches to an appropriate column name and few manipulations are performed using dplyr package.

For some reason, when I use : “b[match(input$defInput, a)] %in% c(0:14)”, it does not work, though when I manually check “alpha %in% c(0:14)”, it works fine.

I checked the classes of the arguments, and they seem to match. Any suggestions to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    filtered <- reactive({
        a = c ("Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4")
        b = c ("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta")
             df %>% 
            filter (b[match(input$defInput, a)] %in% c(0:14))
})

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    filtered <- reactive({
        a = c ("Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4")
        b = c ("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta")
             df %>% 
            filter (alpha %in% c(0:14))
})
```

Comment: `b` is not a column in the data frame `df`. So, what are you trying to filter?

Comment: Perhaps you can post a reproducible example and others can use to help with working code. In the meantime, you may want to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492280/non-standard-evaluation-nse-in-dplyrs-filter-pulling-data-from-mysql

Comment: assigned vector b  to include the names of the column. b[match(option1, a)] = alpha; b[match(option2, a)] = beta;  Idea was to use

Comment: thanks Gopala for the link and help..will use lazy eval to assign the column name

Comment: Following Code worked

Comment: server <- function(input, output, session) {
        filtered <- reactive({
           a = c ("Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4")
           b = c ("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta")
                 df %>% 
                filter_(interp(~ y %in% c(0:14), y =   as.name(b[match(input$defInput, a)])))
})

Comment: You don't really need to maintain `b` in my opinion. Something like `names(.)` or `names(df)` should work since your `b` is a vector of names. That way, you are not hard coding it.