# how can dplyr functions discriminate columns and variables with the same name?

Tags: r, dplyr

Sometimes I accidently create a variable that has the same name with a column in a `data.frame` and later use the variable in `dplyr` functions. the name is often treated as column name not variable name. See the follow example:

```
library(dplyr)

packageVersion("dplyr")
#> [1] '0.6.0'
mtcars %>% filter(mpg == 21)
#>   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
mpg.val <- 21
mtcars %>% filter(mpg == mpg.val)
#>   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
mpg <- 21
mtcars %>% filter(mpg == mpg)
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> ...
```

In the third case, how to tell filter that the second `mpg` is a variable name not a column name and get the results as the first two cases? (In addition I am using dplyr 0.6.0.)

---

`get` results generated by `reprex`:

```
mpg <- 21
mtcars %>% filter(mpg == get("mpg"))
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> ...
```

Add environment works:

```
mtcars %>% filter(mpg == get("mpg", .GlobalEnv))
#  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-standard evaluation (NSE) in dplyr's filter\_ & pulling data from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492280/non-standard-evaluation-nse-in-dplyrs-filter-pulling-data-from-mysql)

Comment: @AdamQuek, How does the linked question solve my problem? Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: @mt1022 `mtcars %>% filter(mpg == get("mpg"))` works for me. `dplyr 0.5.0`

Comment: @RonakShah, I have to use `get("mpg", .GlobalEnv)` to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.GlobalEnv`

```
mtcars %>%
     filter(mpg == .GlobalEnv$mpg)
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: Or `mtcars %>% filter(mpg == get("mpg"))`.