# Why using get to access variables in Global env without specify environment explicitly works for dplyr 0.5.0 but not for 0.6.0?

Tags: r, dplyr

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300978/how-can-dplyr-functions-discriminate-columns-and-variables-with-the-same-name) about accessing variable in global environment with the same name as one of the column name in dplyr functions. One solution I received was using `get`. However, new matter arises. Without specify environment explicitly, the result is different (see the following), Could someone explain why?

```
# dplyr 0.6.0
mpg <- 21
mtcars %>% filter(mpg == get("mpg"))
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> ...

# dplyr 0.5.0
mtcars %>% filter(mpg == get("mpg"))
#  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: I assume it's a side effect of the major changes from 0.5 to 0.6 in terms of standard evaluation / non-standard evaluation approaches

Comment: I think the new behavior makes sense, while the old one was a bug. `get`, by default, should look in the current environment rather in the parent, hence the current behavior is the correct one which makes your question kind of obsolete IMO.

Comment: Agreed. Also "Explicit is better than implicit".